# Guardar proyecto Django una vez esta en producción

Tags: python, django, apache, deployment

Tengo una duda, después de configurar la base de datos PostgreSQL, Python, Apache2, Django, WSGI, y también Django Rest Framework, psycopg2, Pillow cuando entro a `midominio.com` he logrado que me aparezca que el servidor Django funciona.

Ahora bien, estoy haciendo cambios en el proyecto y solo me aparecen cuando entro en el servidor de desarrollo (`./manage.py runserver midominio:8000`) si entro por el dominio simplemente sale `it worked`, pero no veo nada de los cambios que haga en el proyecto.

No me sale ningún error de `imports`, ni de nada, incluso he hecho un `./manage.py check --deploy` y me da 7 warnings, que me falta? Estoy haciendo algo mal? También he hecho un `./manage.py test proyecto` y me sale que no hay ningún fallo.

**EDITO:**

Ya me daba miedo hacer un `restart` porque me rompe el deploy.... pues resulta que el reload igual.... ahora `Internal Server Error`

No he tocado nada del Apache, solo he tocado el proyecto por FTP y he hecho el reload.

Alguien sabe a que puede ser debido que después de `reload` o `restart` de Apache se carga el deployment del WSGI?

Estos son los warning:

```
urls.py:21: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got my_app.views.home). Pass the callable instead.
  url(r'^$', 'my_app.views.home', name='home'),

System check identified some issues:
```

**WARNINGS:**

- ?: (security.W004) You have not set a value for the SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS setting. If your entire site is served only over SSL, you may want to consider setting a value and enabling HTTP Strict Transport Security. Be sure to read the documentation first; enabling HSTS carelessly can cause serious, irreversible problems.
- ?: (security.W006) Your SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF setting is not set to True, so your pages will not be served with an 'x-content-type-options: nosniff' header. You should consider enabling this header to prevent the browser from identifying content types incorrectly.
- ?: (security.W007) Your SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER setting is not set to True, so your pages will not be served with an 'x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block' header. You should consider enabling this header to activate the browser's XSS filtering and help prevent XSS attacks.
- ?: (security.W008) Your SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT setting is not set to True. Unless your site should be available over both SSL and non-SSL connections, you may want to either set this setting True or configure a load balancer or reverse-proxy server to redirect all connections to HTTPS.
- ?: (security.W012) SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE is not set to True. Using a secure-only session cookie makes it more difficult for network traffic sniffers to hijack user sessions.
- ?: (security.W017) You have 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, but you have not set CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY to True. Using an HttpOnly CSRF cookie makes it more difficult for cross-site scripting attacks to steal the CSRF token.
- ?: (security.W019) You have 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, but X_FRAME_OPTIONS is not set to 'DENY'. The default is 'SAMEORIGIN', but unless there is a good reason for your site to serve other parts of itself in a frame, you should change it to 'DENY'.

System check identified 7 issues (0 silenced).

Pido disculpas, porque aún no sé muy bien como estructurar las preguntas o darle formato.

**EDITO:**

Por cierto esta es la línea de mi archivo `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^$', 'my_app.views.home', name='home'),
```

**EDITO:** Este es el único log que me deja dicho error. `Internal Server Error 500`.

```
[Mon May 09 13:19:49.067630 2016] [:error] [pid 10053] Not Found: /
```

**EDITO:** Aquí dejo mi configuración de Apache:

```
Alias "/media" "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/sub.domain.com/django/my_project/media"

Alias "/static" "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/sub.domain.com/django/my_project/static"


<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/sub.domain.com/django/my_project/static/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/sub.domain.com/django/my_project/media/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>


WSGIDaemonProcess morpheus python-path=/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/sub.domain.com/django/my_project/:/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/sub.domain.com/django/django_environment/lib/python3.4/site-packages


WSGIProcessGroup morpheus


WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/sub.domain.com/django/my_project/my_project/wsgi.py


WSGIPassAuthorization On


<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/sub.domain.com/django-project/my_project/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

**EDITO:** Al final de los 7 warnings he dejado solo 2 (en teoría mi dominio no va a trabajar en SSL por lo que he leído que no hace falta activar dichos parámetros. Los que he arreglado los he arreglado añadiendo estos parámetros a `settings.py`:

```
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Aún así aún me tira `Error 500` al entrar al proyecto a través del dominio

Aunque hay que decir que al activar todo eso **no puedo iniciar sesión** en el backend `/admin` en el **entorno de desarrollo**.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega información que ayude a comprender tu problema. Coloca los _logs_ relevantes de Django, las 8 advertencias que mencionas, la configuración de Apache, etc. Es importante que seas específico y detallado, para que no tengamos que adivinar que es lo que estás viendo en tu pantalla.

Comment: Coloca la configuración de apache, para revisarla. Busca los logs de apache, incluyendo los logs de errores y colócalos aquí. Los avisos no provocan los errores.

Comment: Coloca la configuración de apache, para revisarla. Perdón, pero este punto es importante y es la tercera vez que sugiero que la compartas. Espero que tengas buenas razones para no hacerlo y espero sinceramente que pronto tengas tu servidor operando.

Comment: Perdona @toledano, ahi la tienes. ;) Y gracias!

Answer (score 2):

La forma fácil para ver tus cambios es recargando apache (que no lo mismo que reiniciar):

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

o

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Hay algunos artículos interesantes para hacer esta tarea como por ejemplo:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2008/12/using-modwsgi-when-developing-django.html

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode#Restarting_Daemon_Processes

Answer (score 0):

me imagino que agregaste el dominio.com a tu lista
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['dominio.com']
Si tienes acceso a una linea de comandos prueba ejecutar tu proyecto con debug=True de esta manera python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 esto debe sacar tu web fuera y prueba entrar por dominio.com